# Laravel store function save excel file as zip and csv file as txt into folder

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using laravel 6.1  and when i use `request()->file('file')->store('avatars')` to store the file then it stores .xlsx file as .zip and .csv file as .txt . How to solve this problem?
My full code is-

```
         $path = request()->file('file')->store('avatars');

        $array = Excel::toArray(new CustomerImport, request()->file('file'));

        $store_customers=Schema::getColumnListing('store_customers');


        return view('pages.import.upload_customer',compact('array','path','store_customers'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a closed PR refering about this problem:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28381

You can try:

```
$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()
```